# Is it still possible to swap erc20 Theta tokens to Theta main net tokens?

Tags: cryptography

Is it still possible to swap erc20 Theta tokens to Theta main net tokens? I have some stored on a ledger that I forgot about and would like to change them obviously! Im hoping this is still possible. any help would be great, thanks in advance!